# use scrapy to crawl an xml webpage

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I need to crawl an xml page http://www.10why.net/sitemap.xml
which is just a table of urls that i want

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import re

thename = "sitemap"

class ReviewSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = thename
    allowed_domains = ['10why.net']
    start_urls = ['http://www.10why.net/sitemap.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        content = hxs.select('//table[@cellpadding="5"]/tbody//a')

        print content
        for c in content:


            file = open('%s.txt' % thename, 'a')
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(c)
            file.close()
```

The content printed is [] (empty list)
I use to be able to crawl things on a normal html page instead of a site map xml page. Please help me. 
PS: I write the file by myself for other reasons.

Comment: Scrapy has a SitemapSpider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess this is because you're looking at the HTML your browser is using to *show* the XML rather than the raw XML as it comes from the server.  When I look at the given URL, I see an XML structure similar to:

```
<urlset>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.10why.net/20130321/bb-nuan/</loc>
      <lastmod>2013-03-21T01:51:31+00:00</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.2</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

You might want to use an XPath expression more like:

```
//urlset/url/loc
```

To get all URLs in the site map.

Comment: 1. how did you get the xml table from the server

Comment: 2. when i print out the first row, i get <HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//urlset/url/loc' data=u'<loc>http://www.10why.net/20130409/zuo-y'>. so how can i get 'http://www.10why.net/20130409/zuo-y' instead?

Comment: content = hxs.select('//urlset/url/loc/text()').extract() works fine. thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was away, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: nah, i still don't know how did u get the raw xml from server

Comment: I just went to the page, right clicked, selected *View Source*.